# Does Visual Studio Test Essentials/Test Runner run web & load tests?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2010

Looking at [Amit Chatterjee's Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/amit_chatterjee/archive/2009/05/14/official-names-for-the-2010-test-products-now-announced.aspx) on the upcoming Visual Studio Test Essentials product and in the image he has (below) he basically he says that all the blue blocks will be in Test Essentials, while all the green will be in Visual Studio Test Edition.

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/amit_chatterjee/WindowsLiveWriter/OfficialNamesforthe2010TestProductsnowan_A5E7/image_thumb_6.png))</sub>

I see Test Runner is on the blue block side - does that mean that I can create the web & load tests (green blocks) in Visual Studio Test Edition, and then using Test Runner in Test Essentials to actually run them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes - You will be able to create the test in Visual Studio Test Edition and use Test Runner to execute them.